# check that table has a record for all ids in a list

Tags: mysql

I have a list of users, a list of events, and a list that connects users to the events they attended.

If a user has attended all of the events in a given month I want to be able to display this, but I cant seem to figure out the best way to do it.

My current solution is to grab a list of all the events for a month, then grab all the event_user rows for a specific user and make sure they match in the server side code, but I was hoping for something more elegant that could cut all of that out, and do it entirely in a mysql query.

An example sql fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fda31e/23 In this example user 1 should return, but user 2 should not. In the real tables there are foreign keys and such but I didnt bother putting them on the fiddle.

My attempted solution is in the fiddle above, but I cant figure out how to use the concatenated events in the where clause.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  (1, 'test1'),
  (2, 'test2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `date`) VALUES
  ('1', '2018-01-02 17:00:00'),
  ('2', '2018-01-03 17:00:00'),
  ('3', '2018-01-04 17:00:00');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_events` (
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `event_id`)
);
INSERT INTO `user_events` (`user_id`, `event_id`) VALUES
  (1, '1'),
  (1, '2'),
  (1, '3'),
  (2, '1'),
  (2, '3');

select user_id, group_concat(event_id) eventIds 
from user_events 
where eventIds = (select group_concat(id) from events where month(date) = 1)
group by user_id;
```

Comment: Can you solve an opposite problem?

Comment: I guess this is what you want to achieve: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fda31e/31/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following query:

```
select user_id,count(event_id) as cnt,group_concat(event_id separator ',') as Event_ids
from user_events
group by user_id
having cnt = (select count(id) from events where month(date) = 1);
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fda31e/31/0)